# Is the Ornstein–Uhlenbeck process stationary in the wide-sense?

Tags: stochastic-processes

[This post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/345773/how-the-ornstein-uhlenbeck-process-can-be-considered-as-the-continuous-time-anal) shows that OU process is AR(1) empirically. It looks like the eigenvalues of the coefficient are all less that one i.e. the process is wide-sense stationary. I find this a bit conterintuitive because OU process clearly has a strong trend before reaching the "steady state" and shouldnt be wide-sense stationary. Can anyone please explain?