# Geometric Brownian Motion With Mean Reversion

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-pde

Is it possible to generate this mean-reverting Ornstein-Uhlenbeck stochastic differential equation 
$$
dx_t = \theta(\mu - x_t)\text{d}t + \sigma \text{d}W_t
$$
in Excel?

Are there any mean-reverting stochastic processes that can be simulated in Excel?

Thanks.

Comment: For sure you can with its discretization: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/345795/288459