# Non-Gaussian Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process and AR(1)

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, finance, stochastic-differential-equations

I am looking into generalizing the Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process to non-Gaussian noise sources.
In the code, I discretized the OU process (Euler-Maryuama discretization) and converted it into an AR(1) model, similar to the answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/345795/290352), where we end up with

$x_{k+1} = \theta(\mu - x_k)\Delta t + \sigma \varepsilon_k\sqrt{\Delta t}$

Since $\varepsilon_k$ is normally distributed, can I not just replace this with another distribution and get a non-Gaussian OU process? It surely is not that simple?

Comment: You will get _a_ non-Gaussian process. What properties do you want the process to have?

Comment: @user619894 I am looking into distributions with fatter tails for which the Gaussian noise assumption does not work as well.